# Altimeter / Altitude Reader apps: can't get them to record multiple named altitude readings etc

Tags: android

I am looking for an integrate barometer-based (not GPS-based) altitude reader / altimeter for Android which can be used when going hiking in a way which would make it acceptably useful. It should do the following:

- At the beginning of the hike, I should be able to click on "New Hike".
- At any point in time during the hike, I should be able to press a button to record the current altitude in meters together with the current time and I should also be able to specify a name so that I can give the name of a landmark (e.g. "bottom house", "first river", "bunch of mushrooms", "red flowers", "first mountain peek", etc...) so that when I look back at the list I can see the altitude. This would be useful since it could help when using a map which has level curves marking altitude differences and altitude marks. Optionally, I should also be able to take a picture and associate it with such recorded altitude reading.
- At the end of the hike, I must be able to click on save, to save the list, giving the list of altitude readings, times, text, and pictures a name (such name appears in the list of hikes accessible from the application).
- Optionally, the application must be able to display a graph with time on the x-axis, altitude on the y-axis, and image thumbnails along the graph which when clicked also display the corresponding text.
- For each hike, each entry in the list of absolute time+altitude+text+thumbnail entries also displays the time lapse and altitude lapse as differential measurements automatically computed from the previous entry or zero for the first entry.
- Optionally, the GPS coordinates of each entry in each hike list should also be stored.

I have searched and searched, but cannot find any Android apps which carry out the above behavior. If anyone knows where I can find such an app, then please let me know.

Comment: That would require the Android device having a pressure sensor. If yours has, check [these search results](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=sensor%20altimeter) or [this app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sensors#group_977).

Comment: Yes, my Samsung Galaxy SIII has a pressure sensor. The problem is that most apps just concentrate on providing a pretty image in their app rather than providing the functionality I describe all in one software, which would make these apps more useful. I wonder whether any exists which does exactly what I describe. (Also, you second link is broken when accessing it via https it seems). Thanks.

Comment: As I never had a need for such, I cannot precisely tell. But following the second link in my last comment, you'll find apps using the sensor (not GPS) for altimetre, so that should narrow down candidates to check. Some of them sound promising in your context (I've just compiled the list when I saw your question, so impressions are fresh ;).

Comment: The problem with most of these is that they are not "recording altimeters". The closest seems to be AltiVario Altimeter, but then again, I cannot associate text and pictures with each "checkpoint".

Comment: I'm afraid the "perfect match" might not exist. But let's look forward to "real answers" before drawing *that* conclusion :)